# Lucene: combining ASCII folding and stemming for French

Tags: lucene

I am implementing a Lucene search for French text. The search must work regardless of whether the user has typed accents or not, and it must also support stemming. I am currently using the Snowball-based French stemmer in Lucene 3.

On the indexing side, I have added an `ASCIIFoldingFilter` into my analyzer, which runs after the stemmer.

However, on the search side, the operation is not reversible: the stemmer only works given the input content contains accents. For example, it stems the `ité` from the end of `université`, but with a user search input of `universite`, the stemmer returns `universit` during query analysis. Of course, since the index contains the term `univers`, the search for `universit` returns no results.

A solution seems to be to change the order of stemming and folding in the analyzer: instead of stemming and then folding, do the folding before stemming. This effectively makes the operation reversible, but also significantly hobbles the stemmer since many words no longer match the stemming rules.

Alternatively, the stemmer could be modified to operate on folded input i.e. ignore accents, but could this result in over-stemming?

Is there a way to effectively do folded searches without changing the behavior of the stemming algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.) Use an exhaustive lemma synonym mapping file

Step 2.) ASCII (ICU) Fold after lemmatizing.

You can get exhaustive French lemmas here:
http://www.lexiconista.com/datasets/lemmatization/

Also, because **lemmatizers** are NOT destructive like **stemmers** you can apply the lemmatizer multiple times, perhaps your lemmatizer also contains accent-free normalizations... Just apply the lemmatizer again.